British government overcharging social security?
HMRC defines employee national insurance (social security) contributions simplistically:
0% Up to £1,048 a month, then
8% to £4,189, and
2% thereafter

and verbosely:

From the Primary Threshold (PT) of £1,048 per month, employees start paying National Insurance. Above the Upper Earnings Limit (UEL) of £4,189, employees pay a lower rate.
Employees pay 8% between Primary Threshold and Upper Earnings Limit, then 2%.

The annual Primary Threshold is presumably £12,576 (=1048*12).
Example 1. Using HMRC's calculator with £12,576 gross annual income, we're told:
Gross income        £12,576.00
Personal Allowance  £12,570.00
Taxable Income           £6.00
National Insurance       £0.48
Take-home pay       £12,575.52

Given that income is equal to the (presumed) annual Primary Threshold, national insurace should be zero.
Example 2. From HMRC:

If...you earn £1,000 in a week you’ll pay: nothing on the first £242, 8% (£58) on your earnings between £242.01 and £967
2% (£0.66) on the remaining earnings above £967...your National Insurance payment will be £58.66 for the week.

The calculator gives:
 Gross income        £52,000.00
 ...
 National Insurance   £3,050.60

We can see £1,000 weekly is £52,000 annually, but £58.66 * 52 = £3050.32 — HMRC's calculator disagrees with HMRC's worked example.
Is the British Government miscalculating national insurance?
The calculator seemingly works for a Primary Threshold of £12,570 (the [income tax] personal allowance for salaries under £100k) and Upper Earnings Limit of £50,270. Elsewhere, HMRC comments:

government will increase...Upper Earnings Limit...to £50,270, and the NICs Primary Threshold to £9,568 for 2021 to 2022...The NICs Upper Earnings Limit...will remain aligned...at £50,270 for [2022-2026, there's no mention of the Primary Threshold].

For 2021-2022,

Primary Threshold is given as £797 monthly / £9,564 (=797*12) annually,

Upper Earnings Limit £4,189 monthly / £50,268 annually,


suggesting something is going wrong — we're not matching HMRC's annual figure of £9,568 nor £50,270.
Using weekly figures £184 and £967, multiplying
by fifty-two, we get annual charges of £9,568 and £50,284,
seemingly computing the Primary Threshold
correctly. (Albeit, a year is twelve months, not
fifty-two weeks.) The Upper Earnings Limit remains at £967 weekly for 2024-2024.
There's likely something obvious here: A rounding error?
HMRC's CA38 gives weekly, monthly, and yearly figures. E.g., Primary Threshold is £242 weekly, £1,048 monthly, and £12,570 yearly. For calculations, we need to use the yearly figure, the others contain rounding errors:

£12,570/52 = £241.73
£12,570/12 = £1047.50

Why HMRC publishes weekly and monthly figures online, and buries annual figures elsewhere, I don't know — as HMRC's worked (above) example demonstrates, errors arise.

Your question would be clearer if you laid out the examples where you think the calculation is wrong more clearly, together with what you think the correct figures are and why you think so.

Also is your question essentially about rounding when they go from annual figures to monthly/weekly or are you suggesting a bigger problem?
From https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/65faf8afaa9b760011fbdbdc/CA38.pdf I suspect the actual threshold is the smaller annual figure (12570) but they round in the taxpayer's favour when calculating monthly/weekly equivalents.

@GS-ApologisetoMonica The example is: Given that income is equal to the (presumed) annual Primary Threshold, national insurace should be zero. I'll add another.

Added a further example, we see HMRC's calculator disagreeing with HMRC's worked example.

@GS-ApologisetoMonica Thanks for sharing that document: We see Primary Threshold being defined as £242 weekly, £1,048 monthly (x4, makes sense), or £12,570 yearly. How HMRC derive their annual figure, I don't know.

Digging deeper, you're right it's a rounding error. Albeit, it's bigger in the sense that even HMRC can't use their own figures, as their worked example demonstrates. Thanks @GS-ApologisetoMonica

The NI Primary Threshold is currently aligned to the personal allowance for income tax - see for example this page.
As the personal allowance is currently £12570, this is the correct annual figure.
It's likely that they have simply rounded in the employee's favour when calculating the monthly and weekly amounts. There's no reconciliation mechanism for NI; you'll be charged based on those calculations and that's the end of it.
For what it's worth there's some subtlety to the way the annual income tax figures are turned into monthly/weekly figures for PAYE, but they get a lot closer to the "correct" figures and also for anyone who fills in a tax return any inaccuracies are corrected at that point. Some previous discussion on here: 1, 2.

{I'm presuming this works in roughly the same way as US Income Tax witholdings, which I'm using as the basis for my explanation}
The law is laid out to calculate the appropriate periodic insurance charge based on your annual income. For monthly or weekly pay periods, they do the best they can to estimate how much they should charge off of that pay period assuming the pay period is the same throughout the year.
The monthly brackets you show are simply the annual figures divided by 12 and rounded ( 12,570 / 12 = 1047.50 which rounds up to 1048). The weekly brackets is the annual brackets divided by 52 and rounded (12,570 / 52 = 241.73).
Since 1) the annual figures do not divide into 12 exactly, 2) a year does not divide in to an exact number of weeks, and 3) many people do not earn the exact same amount every pay period in a year, there is naturally going to be some rounding error or other inaccuracy when trying to extrapolate a periodic paycheck (especially weekly) to the equivalent annual number. For U  income tax, that results in either a tax bill or tax refund when you file your annual taxes. I am not aware if there is a reconciliation for UK National Insurance, or if they just accept the inaccuracy and ignore any difference (whether in your favor or not).  If you feel that you are being overcharged, then you can research how to dispute the charge and try to recover it, but based on what you've posted it does not seem to be anything egregious in my opinion.
